# Cmake - How to copy files with input data to build output folder

Tags: c++, c, cmake, clion, ctest

I'm using CLion and CMake for project building. I've created Google Test build configuration and my project tree looks like:

[image: project tree]

The tests for tokenizer are simple: tokenizer should open source files and output tokens.

This is my CMakeLists.txt file for tokenizer_test:

```
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIRS}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIRS})
add_subdirectory(test_src)
add_executable(run_tokenizer_tests
    tokenizer_test.cpp ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/includes/tokenizer.h
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/tokenizer.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(run_tokenizer_tests gtest gtest_main)
```

Am I able to place test sources (like 0.cpp on the picture) nearby executable or should I write my own testing scripts? How can I do it?

Comment: Take a look at the [CMake variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html). There are a few which gives you project and source directories that you can use for your tests (by adding them as macros when building, or passing as arguments when running the tests).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, unfortunetely, I found none, so I wrote this.

Comment: @ДмитрийТерехов what do you mean by "test sources" what exactly "0.cpp" contains? Input data for tokenizer_tests?

Comment: @Liastre it's source for tokenizer. Tokenizer takes source file and output found tokens(lexemes).

Comment: And how does your tokeniser expect to receive an input?

Comment: @ДмитрийТерехов so, as I understood you want to place input data for test (0.cpp) to build output folder on configure step, right?

Comment: @Liastre I just want to have access to test files (like 0.cpp). So I can make  something like for file in files do executable [args] file done.

Answer (score 6):

You can call `file(COPY source DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})`

See https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables for other variables.

Here is the snippet from our project that does this and some more.

Overall, this snippet allows you to avoid dependencies on specific file locations on a file system, provided your build directory is alive, because file paths will be hardcoded in your unit-tests.

It simplifies automated builds and checking - no need to track where to `cd` before calling test runner.

It also improves readability of code in unit-tests.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# list all test images

set(test_data

    orig_5_15Fps_3_27.png
    orig_5_15Fps_5_34.png
    ....
)

# Loop over all items in the "test_data" list
# Copy PNG, JPEG and BMP images to the directory, where test binaries are created
# And generate full paths to them for hardcoding in the include file test_config.h

foreach(df ${test_data})

    # copy images to build dir

    if(${df} MATCHES "((jp|pn)g|bmp)$")
        file(COPY ${df} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})   
        set(df_file_path ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${df})
    else()
        set(df_file_path ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${df}) 
    endif()

    # generate some C++ code in CMake variables IMAGE_PATHS and IMAGE_IDS
    # (see below)

    if (NOT IMAGE_PATHS)
        set(IMAGE_PATHS "    \"${df_file_path}\"")
    else()
        set(IMAGE_PATHS "${IMAGE_PATHS},\n    \"${df_file_path}\"")
    endif()

    string(REGEX REPLACE "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" "_" df_id ${df})

    if (NOT IMAGE_IDS)
        set(IMAGE_IDS "    img_${df_id}")
    else()
        set(IMAGE_IDS "${IMAGE_IDS},\n    img_${df_id}")
    endif()
endforeach()

set(TEST_PATH \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}\")

configure_file(test_config.h.in test_config.h @ONLY)  # see below for test_config.h.in 

...
include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )   # make test_config.h visible for compiler
add_executable (some_unit_test some_unit_test.cpp)
add_test(NAME some_unit_test COMMAND some_unit_test WORKING_DIRECTORY ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH})
 ... 
add_executable ( ... )
add_test(  ... )
...
```

File `test_config.h.in`.

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, IT IS AUTOGENERATED!
   All your changes will be overwritten.

   If you want to add new test data files, 
   add them to the `test_data` list in file CMakeLists.txt
*/ 

#ifndef __TEST_CONFIG_H__
#define __TEST_CONFIG_H__

const char* test_path = @TEST_PATH@; //!< full path to test data, without trailing slash

//! full paths to all test images
const char* image_paths[] = {
    @IMAGE_PATHS@
};

enum image_ids { //!< test file names, converted to enum constants
    @IMAGE_IDS@
};

#endif
```

Call to `configure_file` replaces `@TEST_PATH@`, `@IMAGE_PATHS@` and `@IMAGE_IDS@` with their values.

Here is how configured file `test_config.h` in the build directory looks like.

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, IT IS AUTOGENERATED!
   All your changes will be overwritten.

   If you want to add new test data files, 
   add them to the `test_data` list in file CMakeLists.txt
*/ 

#ifndef __TEST_CONFIG_H__
#define __TEST_CONFIG_H__

const char* test_path = "F:/projects/project/build64/test"; //!< full path to test data, without trailing slash


//! full paths to all test images
const char* image_paths[] = {
  "F:/projects/project/build64/test/orig_5_15Fps_3_27.png",
  "F:/projects/project/build64/test/orig_5_15Fps_5_34.png",
   ... 
};

enum image_ids { //!< test file names, converted to enum constants
    img_orig_5_15Fps_3_27_png,
    img_orig_5_15Fps_5_34_png,
...
};

#endif
```

Using in tests:

```
#include "test_config.h"
....     
img0 = cv::imread(image_paths[img_orig_5_15Fps_3_27_png], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

`enum image_ids` is used for readable indexing in the `image_paths` array.  IMHO, it is much better than `image_paths[0]`, as it clearly shows which image is read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) CMake function, with `COPYONLY` flag. It will copy the file without replacing any variable references or other content. Your `CMakeLists.txt` near to `tokenizer_test.cpp` should contain:

```
configure_file(test_src/0.cpp 0.cpp COPYONLY)
```

P.S.: I suggest you to rename each source file and input file according to test you are doing, in your case `0.cpp` should be named something like `tokenizer_test_parse_input.cpp` and it would be better to place this file near to `tokenizer_test.cpp".